# Strange behaviour when querying iOS Keychain using kSecAttrApplicationTag

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, keychain

I'm facing a strange behaviour when trying to store and query a key item with the keychain using a kSecAttrApplicationTag. It seems that even if I get a Status code 0 (Successfully stored) after inserting a 64 bytes random key I fail to retrive/query it afterwards from the keychain. Super weired is that the problem seems to be kind of random (it happens not all the time).

Here some background on what I'm working on and where I encountered the issue. I'm trying to generate/query a 64 bytes random key to be used to encrypt my Realm persistance. The item creation looks as follows:

```
uint8_t buffer[64];
SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, buffer);
NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:sizeof(buffer)];
NSDictionary *item = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                       (__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: tagData,
                       (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: @512,
                       (__bridge id)kSecValueData: keyData,
                       (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible: (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock};
```

and the item query looks as follows:

```
NSDictionary *query = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                        (__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: tagData,
                        (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: @512,
                        (__bridge id)kSecReturnData: @YES};

CFTypeRef dataRef = NULL;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &dataRef);
```

As you may noticed tagData is not defined in the previous code snippets. The thing is if I use the following line of code to create tagData

```
//Approach 1
uint8_t kKeychainIdentifier[] = "an.application.tag";
tagData =  [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)kKeychainIdentifier length:sizeof(kKeychainIdentifier) freeWhenDone:NO];
```

I'm encountering this weired random behaviour. However if I use the following line of code everything seems to be fine and working properly

```
//Approach 2
NSData *tag = ["an.application.tag" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now my question is what exactly is happening within the keychain that I'm not able to have a persistent behaviour? Is the first approach wrong? I observed that when printing out both approaches the hex value differs on the the last two digits, whereas the second approach ends with 00 and the first not. But how can this have an impact on storing and retrieving an item from the keychain if it stays always the same?

Comment: Is the problem on an iOS device or on a Mac simulator?

Comment: Hi, i could reproduce the issue on a iOS simulator. However I‘m facing the issue in Production too. A set of iOS devices seem to be affected. However I can not be 100%. If this was the problem on the real devices. A testflight with some affected user will show.

Comment: @zaph apprently Approach 2 seems to fix the issue also on real devices